# "Если сам он..." - сам - какой член предложения в данном случае?

Tags: синтаксис

А это (подлежащее) удаётся (сказуемое) в том случае (обстоятельство), если сам (?) он (подлежащее) относится (сказуемое) к словам (дополн.) неравнодушно (обст.) и непривычно (обст.)

Спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Местоимение САМ употреблено здесь в роли усилительного слова, в значении, близком к значению частицы "именно", поэтому подлежащее - САМ ОН.

Comment: спасибо, тогда напишу, что частица

Comment: Нет, это местоимение со значением частицы. Морфологическое значение - местоимение, синтаксическая роль -  входит в состав подлежащего, усиливая его значение.

Comment: ох, у меня проблемы с этим)) спасибо еще раз)

Answer (score 1):

> тогда напишу, что частица

Но частица - это часть речи, а не член предложения.В скобках-то указаны члены предложения